# Why is this unmarshaller throwing a MalformedURLException?

Tags: java, jaxb, weblogic, spring-ws

- Weblogic 11g (10.3.5)
- Spring Framework 3.1.3
- Spring Web Services 2.1.1

Spring-ws web service running on Weblogic. The same web service works fine in Tomcat and Spring vFabric, but throws these cryptic exceptions under Weblogic. My implementation code is never reached on Weblogic, rather request handling breaks down at some point during unmarshalling. I've tried to debug through the issue, but two factors complicate that. First, the unmarshaller is coming from Weblogic, which means I don't have the source. Second, the primary exception is coming from java.net.URL, which it seems that the Eclipse debugger cannot inspect local variable values.

Here's the stack trace, with the trace-level logs leading up to it.

```
2013-02-07 13:45:24,523 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '18' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' :: 127.0.0.1] TRACE  - Received request [<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://subdomain.example.com/services/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:SearchRequest>
         <ser:documentType>Email</ser:documentType>
         <ser:lineOfBusiness>TestLOB</ser:lineOfBusiness>
         <ser:businessKey>
            <ser:keyName>TestCode</ser:keyName>
            <ser:value>00000</ser:value>
         </ser:businessKey>
         <ser:dateCreated>
            <ser:startDate/>
            <ser:length/>
         </ser:dateCreated>
      </ser:SearchRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>]
2013-02-07 13:45:24,538 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '18' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' :: 127.0.0.1] TRACE  - SOAPElement [weblogic.webservice.core.soap.SOAPBodyImpl] implements SAAJ 1.1
2013-02-07 13:45:24,554 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '18' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' :: 127.0.0.1] DEBUG  - Looking up endpoint for [{http://ecm.cinfin.com/services/}SearchRequest]
2013-02-07 13:45:24,554 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '18' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' :: 127.0.0.1] DEBUG  - Endpoint mapping [org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping@1587368] maps request to endpoint [public com.example.subdomain.services.model.SearchResponse com.example.subdomain.services.search.endpoint.SearchEndpoint.handleSearch(com.example.subdomain.services.model.SearchRequest)]
2013-02-07 13:45:24,570 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '18' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' :: 127.0.0.1] TRACE  - SOAPElement [weblogic.webservice.core.soap.SOAPHeaderImpl] implements SAAJ 1.1
2013-02-07 13:45:24,570 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '18' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' :: 127.0.0.1] DEBUG  - Testing endpoint adapter [org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter@f24611]
2013-02-07 13:45:24,570 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '18' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' :: 127.0.0.1] TRACE  - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.MessageContextMethodArgumentResolver@1d60bb4] supports [class com.example.subdomain.services.model.SearchRequest]
2013-02-07 13:45:24,570 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '18' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' :: 127.0.0.1] TRACE  - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.XPathParamMethodArgumentResolver@19a6ada] supports [class com.example.subdomain.services.model.SearchRequest]
2013-02-07 13:45:24,585 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '18' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' :: 127.0.0.1] TRACE  - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.adapter.method.SoapMethodArgumentResolver@1d06ba9] supports [class com.example.subdomain.services.model.SearchRequest]
2013-02-07 13:45:24,585 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '18' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' :: 127.0.0.1] TRACE  - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.dom.DomPayloadMethodProcessor@4c61b3] supports [class com.example.subdomain.services.model.SearchRequest]
2013-02-07 13:45:24,585 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '18' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' :: 127.0.0.1] TRACE  - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.SourcePayloadMethodProcessor@a2392e] supports [class com.example.subdomain.services.model.SearchRequest]
2013-02-07 13:45:24,585 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '18' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' :: 127.0.0.1] TRACE  - Testing if argument resolver [org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.jaxb.XmlRootElementPayloadMethodProcessor@580cc5] supports [class com.example.subdomain.services.model.SearchRequest]
2013-02-07 13:45:24,601 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '18' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' :: 127.0.0.1] DEBUG  - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'searchEndpoint'
2013-02-07 13:45:24,601 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '18' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' :: 127.0.0.1] DEBUG  - Resolving exception from endpoint [public com.example.subdomain.services.model.SearchResponse com.example.subdomain.services.search.endpoint.SearchEndpoint.handleSearch(com.example.subdomain.services.model.SearchRequest)]: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[java.net.MalformedURLException]
2013-02-07 13:45:24,601 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '18' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' :: 127.0.0.1] DEBUG  - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'searchEndpoint'
2013-02-07 13:45:24,601 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '18' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' :: 127.0.0.1] DEBUG  - Resolving exception from endpoint [public com.example.subdomain.services.model.SearchResponse com.example.subdomain.services.search.endpoint.SearchEndpoint.handleSearch(com.example.subdomain.services.model.SearchRequest)]: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[java.net.MalformedURLException]
2013-02-07 13:45:24,616 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '18' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' :: 127.0.0.1] DEBUG  - Endpoint invocation resulted in exception - responding with Fault
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: null
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:213) ~[glassfish.jaxb_1.0.0.0_2-1-12.jar:2.1.12]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:184) ~[glassfish.jaxb_1.0.0.0_2-1-12.jar:2.1.12]
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:137) ~[na:1.6.0_24]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.jaxb.AbstractJaxb2PayloadMethodProcessor$Jaxb2SourceCallback.saxSource(AbstractJaxb2PayloadMethodProcessor.java:239) ~[spring-ws-2.1.1.RELEASE-all.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xml.transform.TraxUtils.doWithSource(TraxUtils.java:103) ~[spring-ws-2.1.1.RELEASE-all.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.jaxb.AbstractJaxb2PayloadMethodProcessor.unmarshalFromRequestPayload(AbstractJaxb2PayloadMethodProcessor.java:125) ~[spring-ws-2.1.1.RELEASE-all.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.jaxb.XmlRootElementPayloadMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(XmlRootElementPayloadMethodProcessor.java:49) ~[spring-ws-2.1.1.RELEASE-all.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter.getMethodArguments(DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter.java:259) ~[spring-ws-2.1.1.RELEASE-all.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter.invokeInternal(DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter.java:220) ~[spring-ws-2.1.1.RELEASE-all.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.AbstractMethodEndpointAdapter.invoke(AbstractMethodEndpointAdapter.java:53) ~[spring-ws-2.1.1.RELEASE-all.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.dispatch(MessageDispatcher.java:233) [spring-ws-2.1.1.RELEASE-all.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.receive(MessageDispatcher.java:173) [spring-ws-2.1.1.RELEASE-all.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.support.WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection(WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.java:88) [spring-ws-2.1.1.RELEASE-all.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:59) [spring-ws-2.1.1.RELEASE-all.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923) [spring-webmvc-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852) [spring-webmvc-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882) [spring-webmvc-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789) [spring-webmvc-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) [javax.servlet_1.0.0.0_2-5.jar:2.5]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820) [javax.servlet_1.0.0.0_2-5.jar:2.5]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227) [weblogic.jar:10.3.5.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125) [weblogic.jar:10.3.5.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300) [weblogic.jar:10.3.5.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26) [weblogic.jar:10.3.5.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56) [weblogic.jar:10.3.5.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27) [weblogic.jar:10.3.5.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56) [weblogic.jar:10.3.5.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715) [weblogic.jar:10.3.5.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681) [weblogic.jar:10.3.5.0]
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321) [com.bea.core.weblogic.security.identity_1.1.2.1.jar:1.1.2.1]
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120) [com.bea.core.weblogic.security.wls_1.0.0.0_6-1-0-0.jar:6.1.0.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277) [weblogic.jar:10.3.5.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183) [weblogic.jar:10.3.5.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454) [weblogic.jar:10.3.5.0]
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209) [com.bea.core.weblogic.workmanager_1.10.0.0.jar:1.10.0.0]
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178) [com.bea.core.weblogic.workmanager_1.10.0.0.jar:1.10.0.0]
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: null
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:601) ~[na:1.6.0_24]
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:464) ~[na:1.6.0_24]
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:413) ~[na:1.6.0_24]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:650) ~[na:1.6.0_24]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:186) ~[na:1.6.0_24]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:772) ~[na:1.6.0_24]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737) ~[na:1.6.0_24]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119) ~[na:1.6.0_24]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205) ~[na:1.6.0_24]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522) ~[na:1.6.0_24]
    at weblogic.xml.jaxp.WebLogicXMLReader.parse(WebLogicXMLReader.java:133) ~[weblogic.jar:10.3.5.0]
    at weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryXMLReader.parse(RegistryXMLReader.java:173) ~[weblogic.jar:10.3.5.0]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:211) ~[glassfish.jaxb_1.0.0.0_2-1-12.jar:2.1.12]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Do you have a space in your BEA home directory path or any library paths?  See https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=687629

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this. Classloading does seem to have been the culprit, but it didn't have anything to do with bundled Spring or installation paths. Rather, I had defined an explicit message factory for Spring's SaajSoapMessageFactory. The factory method on `javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory` seems to have been throwing an exception, but has also proved to be entirely unnecessary. I removed this bean from the config and all is well.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that WLS 10.3.5 comes with its own Spring version 2.5.6.SEC01. So by default, WLS always uses that version, since it is loaded by the higher classloader. That might cause the UnmarshalException you see.

Is your spring library in the WebLogic Application APP-INF/lib or your web application WEB-INF/lib? If the spring 3.1.3 is at the application level, you need to create a weblogic-application.xml with the below entry

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-application>
    <prefer-application-packages>
        <package-name>org.apache.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.springframework.*</package-name>
    </prefer-application-packages>
</weblogic-application>
```

If it is at the web application level, add the following entry to the weblogic.xml

```
<prefer-web-inf-classes>true<prefer-web-inf-classes>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this sort of exception is thrown from WebLogic deployments which have a space in either the installation directory path or included library paths.  Please check your paths.  The fix for this is to re-install on paths without spaces and/or to move your libraries to paths without spaces in them.

[Relevant forum discussion on Oracle's site.](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=687629)